# Display images in desending order from storage (or do I need to use firestore)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

in our app each time users are posting 2 pictures that are being saved to different folders and being pulled to display in another page. Sometimes the images are displaying out of order due to data being pulled I'm assuming.

I want to display the images that are taken the same day next to one another in descending order.

I see in documentations that are being mentioned that `StorageMetadata` to get metadata from the images but when I click my `Other Metadata` in firebase storage it shows nothing.

There is `orderBy('desc')` but that is for `Firebase`. I want to display images in descending order and if the user skips posting an image then it would skip and go to the next line.

This is what I have so far. How can I pull the images in descending order?

```
    const getFrontImage = async () => {
        const imageRefs = await firebase.storage().ref().child(user + '/FrontPic/').listAll();
        const urls = await Promise.all(imageRefs.items.map((ref) => ref.getDownloadURL()));
        // this is to get the metadata but there is a list of images in that folder. 
    // if I user StorageMetadata() on .listAll() it gives an error since it's not an object.
        const date = await firebase.storage().ref().child(user + '/FrontPic/').StorageMetadata();
        console.log("<><><> This is the metadata " + date);
        setFrontImage(urls);
    }
```

Comment: what do you get in `date` variable?

Comment: [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: firebase.storage(...).ref(...).child(...).StorageMetadata is not a function]